# Unrecognized configuration section publishers in CCNet.config when adding slackPublisher integration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

The Slack integration for CCNet is neat https://github.com/jrjackso/CCNetSlackPublisher but I get this error when adding the  to the ccnet.exe.config file:

```
"Unrecognized configuration section publishers. (C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.exe.Config line 167)"
```

I'm running CCnet version 1.8.5.0 (that's the File Version on ccnet.exe at least). I tried copying the dlls from that version into the CCNetSlackPublisher solution before I built it but that didn't change anything.

Does the `<publishers>` section need to be inside anything besides just the  tag? I just put it at the bottom of the file, between `</runtime>` and `</configuration>`.

Comment: Can you add the detail of the .exe config around the line suggested (167). My inclination at the moment is to suggest you should be putting this config in `ccnet.config` not in `ccnet.exe.config`

Comment: Yea that's correct. I didn't notice there were two so similarly named files and added to the wrong one.